# Using ADONET SqlClient library how to access the plain-text value of an encrypted column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2017, encryption, ado.net

In a SQL Server 2017 database running on my development PC, a column in a particular table is encrypted with a column encryption key.

```
  CREATE TABLE Test(
        id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        patientid int,       
        myencryptedcolumn varbinary(2000)   
        ENCRYPTED WITH (ENCRYPTION_TYPE = DETERMINISTIC,
        ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
        COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = MYCEK) NOT NULL
    )
```

In a stored procedure I'm able to decrypt the value using the column encryption key. But I'm also trying to test the ability of the ADO.NET SqlClient library to retrieve the plain-text value transparently and am not having any success there: the encrypted value is always returned to the client program.

Following [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/sqlclient-support-always-encrypted?view=sql-server-ver15) I've granted the following permissions to

`[{My Dev PC Name}\{MyAccount}]`  :

> **VIEW ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION**

> **VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY DEFINITION**

But that user has **VIEW ANY DEFINITION** already, as confirmed in SSMS Security->Logins-Properties->Securables.

And then, using the ADO.NET SqlClient library, I open a connection to the database using `Integrated Security` when logged in to the dev PC as the account mentioned above and with   `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` tag in the connection string.

The SqlClient.SqlCommand object in the client app has these properties:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT myencryptedcolumn FROM Test where id = 100";
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
```

Multiple tuples are returned by the query and piped into a System.Data.DataTable:

```
 var DA = new SqlDataAdapter();
 var T = new System.Data.DataTable();
 DA.SelectCommand = cmd; 
 DA.Fill(T);
 string plaintext = BitConverter.ToString((byte[])T.Rows[0][0]); -- get col value from 1st row
```

But variable `plaintext` always contains a hex string representing the encrypted value not the plain-text value.

Unless I am misreading the Microsoft documentation, the ADO.NET client library should be able to decrypt `myencryptededcolumn` client-side since the user executing the query (i.e. me, per the Integrated Security setting in the connection string) has the required permissions.

What am I overlooking?  Am I supposed to be explicitly fetching the column encryption key and/or its definition and injecting that into some object in the ADO.NET client library?  Is there another database permission involved?